# Ajax request not executed returns undefined

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

I am designing an online multiple-choice test so the user picks one of the 3 answers(radio buttons) and then submits his/her answers. Once the submit button is pressed i need to calculate the results which i am using AJAX requests to compare each answer separately with the use of a PHP script which retrieves questions one by one as well based on the AJAX request parameter.

This is my AJAX request:

```
function calculateResults(){
  totalPoints = 0;
  var qNum = 10;
  while(qNum != 0){
  $.ajax({
      method : "GET",
      url: "php-scripts/testing-questions.php",
      data: {queNum : qNum},
      success: function(data){
          console.log(data);
          //check if radio1 value is set
          if(document.getElementById('r1q' + qNum).check == true){
            var answer = document.getElementById('r1q' + qNum).value;
          }
          //check if radio2 value is set
          else if(document.getElementById('r2q' + qNum).check == true){
            var answer = document.getElementById('r2q' + qNum).value;
          }
          else{ //radio 3 value is set then
             var answer = document.getElementById('r3q' + qNum).value;
          }
          if(data === answer){
              totalPoints++;
          }
        }
     });
     qNum--;
  }
```

}

and this is my PHP script

```
if(isset($_GET['queNum'])){
    $qNum = $_GET['queNum'];
    getAnswer($qNum);
      function getAnswer($num){
          $query = mysqli_query($conn, "SELECT correctAnswer
                              FROM  `Testing` 
                              WHERE  `questionNum` = '".$queNum."' ");
          $row = mysqli_fetch_array($query,MYSQLI_ASSOC);
          echo $row;
          $correA = $row['correctAnswer'];
          echo $correA;
      }
}
```

please note that the $conn variable is set from the config.php file which you are right to assume the connection with the database is working fine also the the echo statements in the function are there for debugging reasons which you should also assume the SQL query runs fine as well.

I have been working on this trying to find what's going wrong for more than a day, it looks simple to but i can't get it to work and no other examples here or anywhere else about AJAX exiting undefined.Anyone with more experience that could help much appreciated.

As requested HTML code below:

```
 <div class="container3">
<div id="startTest">
  <center><button class="checkButtons" onClick="startTimer()" style="width:100px;"> Start Test</button></center>
</div>
<div id="beginTest">
 <input type = "text" name="timer" width="30%" id="timer" value ="10:00" readonly>
</div>
<div id="questions">
 <center>
  <div class="question">
    <p class="q">Question 1: <?php echo $question1 ?></p>
    <input type="radio" id="r1q1" name="answer1" value="Answer 1" checked>Answer A: <?php echo $answerA1 ?> <br>
    <input type="radio" id="r2q1" name="answer1" value="Answer 2">Answer B: <?php echo $answerB1 ?> <br>
    <input type="radio" id="r3q1" name="answer1" value="Answer 3">Answer C: <?php echo $answerC1 ?> <br>
  </div>
   <div class="question">
    <p class="q">Question 2: <?php echo $question2 ?></p>
    <input type="radio" id="r1q2" name="answer2" value="Answer 1" checked>Answer A: <?php echo $answerA2 ?> <br>
    <input type="radio" id="r2q2" name="answer2" value="Answer 2">Answer B: <?php echo $answerB2 ?> <br>
    <input type="radio" id="r3q2" name="answer2" value="Answer 3">Answer C: <?php echo $answerC2 ?> <br>
  </div>
   <div class="question">
    <p>Question 3: <?php echo $question3 ?></p>
    <input type="radio" id="r1q3" name="answer3" value="Answer 1" checked>Answer A: <?php echo $answerA3 ?> <br>
    <input type="radio" id="r2q3" name="answer3" value="Answer 2">Answer B: <?php echo $answerB3 ?> <br>
    <input type="radio" id="r3q3" name="answer3" value="Answer 3">Answer C: <?php echo $answerC3 ?> <br>
  </div>
  <div class="question">
  <p class="q">Question 4: <?php echo $question4 ?></p>
    <input type="radio" id="r1q4" name="answer4" value="Answer 1" checked>Answer A: <?php echo $answerA4 ?> <br>
    <input type="radio" id="r2q4" name="answer4" value="Answer 2">Answer B: <?php echo $answerB4 ?> <br>
    <input type="radio" id="r3q4" name="answer4" value="Answer 3">Answer C: <?php echo $answerC4 ?> <br>
  </div>
   <div class="question">
    <p class="q">Question 5: <?php echo $question5 ?></p>
    <input type="radio" id="r1q5" name="answer5" value="Answer 1" checked>Answer A: <?php echo $answerA5 ?> <br>
    <input type="radio" id="r2q5" name="answer5" value="Answer 2">Answer B: <?php echo $answerB5 ?> <br>
    <input type="radio" id="r3q5" name="answer5" value="Answer 3">Answer C: <?php echo $answerC5 ?> <br>
  </div>
   <div class="question">
   <p class="q">Question 6: <?php echo $question6 ?></p>
    <input type="radio" id="r1q6" name="answer6" value="Answer 1" checked>Answer A: <?php echo $answerA6 ?> <br>
    <input type="radio" id="r2q6" name="answer6" value="Answer 2">Answer B: <?php echo $answerB6 ?> <br>
    <input type="radio" id="r3q6" name="answer6" value="Answer 3">Answer C: <?php echo $answerC6 ?> <br>
  </div>
   <div class="question">
    <p class="q">Question 7: <?php echo $question7 ?></p>
    <input type="radio" id="r1q7" name="answer7" value="Answer 1" checked>Answer A: <?php echo $answerA7 ?> <br>
    <input type="radio" id="r2q7" name="answer7" value="Answer 2">Answer B: <?php echo $answerB7 ?> <br>
    <input type="radio" id="r3q7" name="answer7" value="Answer 3">Answer C: <?php echo $answerC7 ?> <br>
  </div>
   <div class="question">
   <p class="q">Question 8: <?php echo $question8 ?></p>
    <input type="radio" id="r1q8" name="answer8" value="Answer 1" checked>Answer A: <?php echo $answerA8 ?> <br>
    <input type="radio" id="r2q8" name="answer8" value="Answer 2">Answer B: <?php echo $answerB8 ?> <br>
    <input type="radio" id="r3q8" name="answer8" value="Answer 3">Answer C: <?php echo $answerC8 ?> <br>
  </div>
   <div class="question">
   <p class="q">Question 9: <?php echo $question9 ?></p>
    <input type="radio" id="r1q9" name="answer9" value="Answer 1" checked>Answer A: <?php echo $answerA9 ?> <br>
    <input type="radio" id="r2q9" name="answer9" value="Answer 2">Answer B: <?php echo $answerB9 ?> <br>
    <input type="radio" id="r3q9" name="answer9" value="Answer 3">Answer C: <?php echo $answerC9 ?> <br>
  </div>
   <div class="question">
    <p class="q">Question 10: <?php echo $question10 ?></p>
    <input type="radio" id="r1q10" name="answer10" value="Answer 1" checked>Answer A: <?php echo $answerA10 ?> <br>
    <input type="radio" id="r2q10" name="answer10" value="Answer 2">Answer B: <?php echo $answerB10 ?> <br>
    <input type="radio" id="r3q10" name="answer10" value="Answer 3">Answer C: <?php echo $answerC10 ?> <br>
  </div>
    <button class="checkButtons" onClick="calculateResults()" style="width:100px;"> Submit Answers</button>
</center>
</div>
```

Comment: Did you test the PHP is really can turn some data by visiting `http://localhost:8888/php-scripts/testing-questions.php`?if the PHP can't event return data,then that mean something wrong with your PHP code

Comment: Check `getAnswer()`, `$queNum` != `$num` ...  You pass `$num` but use a variable called `$queNum`?!

Comment: Already did that thats why i have the echo statements there. I testsd it with both static and url parameters values

Comment: So have you fix your issue? Was it just a typo?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In first look, your code doesn't shows any problems.

Your PHP script should be. `getAnswer($num)` should be  `getAnswer($qNum)`
and in query, should have `$qNum` variable used instead of `$queNum`.

```
 if(isset($_GET['queNum'])){
        $qNum = $_GET['queNum'];
        getAnswer($qNum);
          //$qNum not $num
          function getAnswer($qNum){
              $query = mysqli_query($conn, "SELECT correctAnswer
                                  FROM  `Testing` 
                                  WHERE  `questionNum` = '".$qNum."' ");
              $row = mysqli_fetch_array($query,MYSQLI_ASSOC);
              $correA = $row['correctAnswer'];
              echo $correA;
              exit;
          }
    }
```

Comment: @A.Wolff Thanks for calling.

Comment: Ya, would be cool to heard about downvoter. I'm not a PHP dev, so maybe I (we?!) miss something obvious?!...

Comment: I've updated my answer, It should work ? and what we missed ?

Comment: i have updated my code based on your suggestions but i still get 500 internal server error

Comment: Can you see in console ? Is there Ajax calls successfully? And server side works

Comment: You should defined you var answer globally, you won't be able to access those in if scope and then access after if/else, define var answer on the top.

Comment: http://imgur.com/a/jRIUV   here you can see a screenshot of my consolse

Comment: Can you update your full code with HTML, so I can check ?

Comment: @marioszachariou Is everything okay, If answer helped then upvote and accept, that will encourage other people to use the solution.